# Unzip a zip file on shared folder remotely?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have (and only have) read/write access to a shared folder of a Windows server. There is a big zip file in the folder. I have a slow connection to the server. Is it possible to unzip the zip file remotely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You need some kind of access to issue commands on the remote server, either through RDP, Powershell Remoting, PSEXEC, or some other method.